# Why is my Related Entity Mapping field only returning one result when there are multiple listed

Tags: content-hub

I am currently working through setting up my connection between Content Hub and Sitecore using Sitecore Connect for Content Hub (SCCH). I have a `Document` entity that has multiple `M.Asset` children associated to it.

After reading the documentation, my understanding is that the `Related Entity Mapping` would be the field I would want to create to represent that association within my Sitecore environment. However, there is not really too much information to go off of and perhaps I am missing something.

Here is my CMP configuration in Sitecore:
[image]

Which is reflected looking up the relation within the entity API here:
[image]

And references my Sitecore template like this:
[image]

And as you can see lists 3 different M.Asset items when you click on the `DocumentToAssets` href here:

[image]

I can tell that the connection appears to be set up somewhat correctly as it does return one of my `M.Asset`'s in my item that gets returned in my Sitecore bucket. However, shouldn't there be 3 of them?

Additionally, I do not understand how this works with relating entities back to each other. It is my understanding (and seems to be confirmed by what I watched in [this demo on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Yjwt8MVz0-4?t=2446)) that you should be able to create a relationship between the two entities in Sitecore. They talk about creating the relationship between `Ingredients` and `Recipes` and say that it should be defined by creating a `Related Entity Mapping`. However, I do not understand how this works. Would someone be able to help explain this for me?